# MFC, How do I change the capiton of TabCtrl

Tags: mfc, caption, ctabctrl

I know the InsertItem is for add new tab in tabctrl, but I need change the caption of tab after create, I use keyword tabctrl and caption to search the old article ,but no relation problem to solve it, hot do I change the caption of tab page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK,

I got the solution, as follow code

```
TC_ITEM TabCtrlItem;

switch(m_tabCtrl.GetCurSel())
{
case TAB1:
    TabCtrlItem.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    TabCtrlItem.pszText = _T("Some Text");
    m_tabCtrl.SetItem(TAB1, &TabCtrlItem );
```

Comment: For other skill, must use CString to convert to LPWSTR, is use CString str; LPWSTR ptr = str.GetBuffer(0); And remeber to str.ReleaseBuffer()